# How do I use a publicly hosted image as the background for a visualforce page?

Tags: image, background, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to use this image as the background for a visualforce page without repeats. This is the code I have so far, but it's not working. Do I have to save the image in Salesforce first. If so, could you walk me through that? Thanks.

```
<body style="background-image: url('{http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg}')no-repeat top fixed;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce will provide the body tag for you. Instead you should use a `style` element or `<apex:stylesheet/>` to define the body style.

See [Using Custom Styles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The image you want to use for body tag is pointing to outside salesforce, hence it might be blocked.

Solution could be:

1. Either download the image in static resource and use  tag as mentioned by Daniel, which is always a good practice.
2. Add the URL in the [remote site setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm) from setup.